# Wifi doesn't work after installation

Tags: wifi

During installation of elementary os it worked perfectly.
On reboot it stopped working.
I tried to do all software updates but the wifi card still doesn't work!

elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera
linux 5.4.0-47-generic

[image]
[image]

Comment: I found the solution myself.

Apparently the problem is due to the Realtek 8822c video card driver (which is missing the rtw8822c_wow_fw.bin file needed to correctly load the rtw8822c_wow_fw.bin driver)

The solution is to download the latest version of linux-firmware from:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/snapshot/linux-firmware-20200918.tar.gz

Extract and copy the contents of the rtw88 folder to /lib/firmware/rtw88

Restart the operating system.

When restarting the wifi card will be fully functional!

Comment: Your solution worked for me! Thanks alot after hours to see what was the cause you solved the issue.